# canvas.todataurl reurn null value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In android phonegap application I crated canvas using html and display image in that canvas.then usingcanvas.toDataURL(image/jpg) tried to convert image into base64 string but it return null value.
How to solve this problem?
hoe to convert image into base64string?

Mycoding:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
 <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   // window.onload = fucntion() {  

        var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload = function() { 
            cxt.drawImage(img,0,0);
           alert(" ");
            var dataURL=myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
            // return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            alert(dataURL);
        };
        img.src='flower.jpg';

    //};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toDataURL is not implememented in android 2.x, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901 for discussion.

Comment: then how to covert image into base64string in android phonegap? please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for your reply I  got that js.It works fine.thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

As @gmh04 mentioned the toDataURL is broken for Canvas in Android 2.x. There used to be a [CanvasPlugin](http://www.ryangillespie.com/downloads/CanvasPlugin.java) but the developer is no longer supporting it or at least that's the way it seems. Other than that I'd look at using the [FileReader.readAsDataUrl](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileReader_read_as_data_url) to read the image as base64 data.